# Javascript global function setting local variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Why does this return 'foo', not 'foobar'? I need function g to modify (non-global) var v, yet function g is a global function. Thanks.

```
f();

function f() {
  var v = 'foo';
  g(v);
  alert(v);
}

function g(v) {
  v = v+'bar';
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you return v from g(v) call but you do not reassign v

```
f();

function f() {
  var v = 'foo';
  v = g(v);  //you need to assign what is returned
  alert(v);
}

function g(v) {
  v = v+'bar';
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because javascript only works by value, not by reference. See John Hartsock's answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Primitive</strike> ALL arguments in javascript (the string argument to g, in this case) are pass-by-value instead of pass-by-reference, which means the `v` you're working with in function g(v) is a copy of the `v` in function f.

`Edit:` all arguments are passed by value, not just primitives.

Comment: **All** arguments in JavaScript are passed by value.

Comment: My mistake, you're right. Non-primitives are passed by value as well, but you can modify their properties.

Comment: Yup.  That's a really frequent argument that pops up, but the key is that the term "call-by-reference" (like "call-by-value" of course) has a pretty specific meaning, and the fact that values can be references to objects is a frequent source of confusion.  Too bad they didn't call it "call-by-back-pointer" or something :-)